# Using pthreads to create an asynchronous timeout in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to create some sort of asynchronous timeout in PHP.

And I'm using the PECL extension pthreads to do so with multithreading.

The asynchronous timeout works perfectly, but the reference doesn't.

I'm using PHP 5.5.8 for this test.

```
class ParentClass {
    public $test;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function test() {
        echo $this->test;
    }
}

class Timeout extends Thread {
    private $seconds;
    private $parent;

    public function __construct($seconds, &$parent){
        $this->seconds = $seconds;
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function run(){
        sleep($this->seconds);
        $this->parent->test();
    }
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$parent->test = "Hello.\n";
$timeout = new Timeout(2, $parent);
$timeout->start();
$parent->test = "Bye.\n";
$parent->test();
```

Expecting

```
Bye.
Bye.
```

Getting

```
Bye.
Hello.
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I must assume that starting a thread will NOT use the same memory objects, so your ParentClass actually gets copied, not noticing that the internal value changes. There is a hint in the docs: Only serializable values can be stored - this makes me think values WILL get serialized when executed. You should probably var_dump the parent class to check if it is the same object

Comment: @Sven Alright, so a singleton is an option? Or some other kind of static class?

Comment: I'm having the idea stackables might be the solution.. I already know it's not the same object since I get different returns. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stackable.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use sleep() for multi-threaded applications, the underlying implementation that is called by PHP is meant to cause a process to sleep, not the threads within a process. Mileage will vary, some implementations may well cause a thread to sleep but you cannot and should not rely on it.

usleep is more suitable for multi-threading in that it is designed to cause threads to sleep, not processes, however, it also leaves threads in an non-receptive state.

pthreads has built into it proper synchronization methods designed for multi-threading that leave threads in a receptive state while waiting for something to occur.

References do not work, nor do they have to, if you wish to pass an object among multiple contexts for manipulation, the object should descend from pthreads.

```
<?php
define("SECOND", 1000000);

class ParentClass extends Stackable {

    public function test() {
        echo $this->test;
    }

    public function run(){}

    public $test;
}

class Timeout extends Thread {

    public function __construct($seconds, $parent){
        $this->seconds = $seconds;
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function run(){
        $this->synchronized(function(){
            $this->wait(
                SECOND * $this->seconds);
        });
        $this->parent->test();
    }

    private $seconds;
    private $parent;
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$parent->test = "Hello.\n";
$timeout = new Timeout(2, $parent);
$timeout->start();
$parent->test = "Bye.\n";
$parent->test();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) I'll be sure to use it next time.