# does php has a function that Asynchronously timeout the script

Tags: php

I want to execute a script that should asynchronously timeout every 15min or some default time.

1. set_time_limit is good fit but it doesn't consider dbqueries or process outside the execution
2. pcntl* is also good fit but having the fear of overlapping signals

Comment: Not the exact way you are looking but, if you are using unix how about using timeout? this will ensure that no matter what happens in the script it will stop at the timeout... however this is done in the bash level ... meaning that you either call your whole script with it and it kills the whole script and if this is running through a script you will need to use shell_exec or something like that...  https://linuxize.com/post/timeout-command-in-linux/   so for example calling your script from inside a running php file will look like : $shell = shell_exec(timeout 15m php "yourScriptFile.php");

Comment: Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22140649/1685196)